# Can POS terminal connect directly to payment gateway OR merchant account over IP network?

Tags: payment-gateway, point-of-sale, javapos

I am looking of POS terminal which support signature capture, pin PAD and ethernet.  Using ethernet and IP network POS terminal should be able to communicate directly to payment gateway/similar system to process card payment.  Steps are :

1. PC software sends command to POS to process payment and tells customer to swipe card
2. Customer swipes card and if required provide signature OR PIN
3. On successful transaction, POS terminal updates PC software with authorization code, card info (last 4 digit/cvv/exp date etc.) and transaction ref. number
4. PC software can also pull signature if applicable.

Please share your views on this.

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
VR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You process is correct. Generally the main monetic actors give you a library (dll or jar) which integrate

- pos interface (no real standards exists) that you can used in your software (credit, debit, cancel...)
- peripheral interface for dialog between their library and the connected pin pad
  and depends of your system system
- a monetic interface which implements dialog between your pos and remote monetic gateway (pos <-> monetic gateway <-> bank )
- a local monetic server wich implements dialog between your libray and remote monetic gateway and lets you manage your transactions 
  You can watch on forum www.kasstore.com, they integrate many monetic interface for their product